# Условие в строке кода

Tags: php

Всем привет. 
Имеется условие:

```
if($message == 'Бот инфа') { бла бла бла }
```

В чем суть. Нужно, чтобы при написании, например, фразы "Бот инфа что" или любая другая фраза (с обязательным использованием "Бот инфа") написанная в чате, выполнялось условие.

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения, как вариант, или поиск подстроки.

Comment: И не забывать про формат (encoding) данных, используя mb_ функции строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inText = 'Бот инфа что';
$pos = strripos($inText, 'Бот инфа');
if ($pos === false) {
    echo 'Не найдено';
} else {
    echo 'бла бла бла' ; 
}
```